# Issues proving a basis via wedge product

Tags: integration, analysis, fourier-series

On a quiz I was given the problem" a series that is a basis for $[-1,1]$ is $ \sum_0^{\infty} c_n P_n $, where $ P_n $ is a polynomial and each polynomial $P_n$ is orthonormal to the others. Using the dot product definition used in Fourier series, what is the formula for computing $c_5$?"
I really have no idea.i believe we are supposed to use the wedge product? But I'm not sure how to use that. Maybe 
$\int_{-1}^1  \sum_0^{5} c_n P_n dx $?
That is really the only thing I can think of but I don't know what to do with it or how to apply it. 
I believe the polynomial is called a legendre polynomial?

Comment: In $L^{2}(l,r)$ with $f: (l,r) \to \mathbb{R}$, 

$$\begin{align}
c_n &= \langle f, e_n \rangle \\
&= \int_{l}^{r} f(x)e_n(x) dx
\end{align}$$

Where $f(x)$ is your initial profile and $e_n(x)$ is your $n^{th}$ eigenfunction.

Comment: @Mattos  I don't understand what the first line says, I don't know that notation. Maybe turn into an answer, and I'll up vote?

Comment: Which part don't you understand, the $L^{2}(l,r)$ part or the $c_{} = \langle f, e_{n} \rangle$? And you asked this question months ago..

Comment: I know I did. I just realized these comments are here. The L^2 bit. I think the \langle represents an inner/wedge product, correct?

Comment: $L^{2}$ defines the space we are working in.. $L^{2}$ is the space of square integrable functions (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Space.html)) and $f : (l,r) \to \mathbb{R}$ says $f$ (our initial profile) is a function that takes inputs from the region $(l,r)$ and outputs a value in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: And yes, the $\langle \cdot \rangle$ represents the _inner product_, which in $L^{2}$ is the integral I described above (in $\mathbb{R}$, $\langle \cdot \rangle$ is the dot product, $\sum_{j} x_{j} y_{j}$).